# Split a string to an array with php

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this:

> https://www.google.comhttp://www.facebook.comhttp://www.apple.com

And I'd like to split that string to an array like:

> array[0]='https://www.google.com'
>
> array[1]='http://www.facebook.com'
>
> array[2]='http://www.apple.com'

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: explode() is ur friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put in a delimiter like a comma to separate the string in to noticeable sections, then use the explode function to break it up into an array

```
$newstring = str_replace('http', ',http', $yourstring); 
$newstring = ltrim($newstring, ','); //remove first one
$result = explode(',' , $newstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some great ways to achieve that goal.

Comment: and this is not considered as an answer

Comment: @AvinashBabu How does it not answer the question which is "Is there a way to accomplish this?"?

Comment: it must be a comment ..;)

Comment: @AvinashBabu but how? It is a direct and precise answer to the question. And maybe a lesson in learning to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
I think it should work.
You can do it.